# Tomcat 9 XSD for server.xml and context.xml

Tags: tomcat, xsd, tomcat9

I tried to add a xsd for the configuration of tomcat. But I could not find any.
Can somebody provide server.xml xsd and also for context.xml.
Don't understand why apache does not have some on their web site.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"   SSLEngine="on"/>
...
```

Comment: An XSD for `<Server>` and `<Context>` wouldn't be very useful, since most elements have an open list of attributes. However, you can write an XSD based on the [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/index.html).

Comment: It does not help but answer it. :-)

Comment: I voted to close it as duplicate, since Mark's answer is still up-to-date after all these years. :-)